# Как обновить Ubuntu 15.10 если умерли репозитории для моей версии

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Столкнулся с проблемой невозможности установки\обновления пакетов.
При попытке обновления получаю ошибки 404.

Comment: Может стоит перейти на lts версии

Comment: Они есть в old-releases.ubuntu.com

Comment: если нужно всего лишь выполнить команду без ошибок, то: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ (15.10==willy). но обновлений там, конечно, нет: версия уже не поддерживается.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Т.Е. Я не смогу обновить ОС через old-releases.ubuntu.com ?

Comment: а смысл обновляться на что-нибудь тоже уже не поддерживаемое (доменное имя old-releases как бы намекает)? обновляйтесь на какую-нибудь пока живую версию, как написано в ответе.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ну я и инею в виду обновление до свежего дистрибутива.
Хочу поставить 16 версию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У меня сейчас такая же задача только с 9.04 до 16.04 серверной версии.

Протестировали 2 пути решения. Первый - это последовательное обновление до нужной версии:

```
~# apt-get install update-manager-core
~# do-realise-upgrade
```

Если выдает ошибку об отсуствии репозитория под версию, замените содержимое /etc/apt/ sources.list на (проверте название старой версии):

```
##  upgraded sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

После 50 тестов, упешно прошли только 3. Тесты проводились на серверах Supermicro локально, удаленно по ssh и IPMI. Критерием было - сохранить удаленное подлюченияе без вмешательства оператора на другом конце.

Второй вариант - это создание автоматической установки при помощи preseed файла. Делаются бэкапы всех ключевых файлов настройки, создается диск отсылается на объект, востанавливается удаленное соединение с сохраненными настройками. Способ медленный и затратный требуется присуствие оператора; из 4 тестов успешных 4.

Если локальная машина, сохраните копии файлов настройки, базы данных и важные фалы и просто поставте с ноля систему.

Ссылки

- https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs02.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TrustyUpgrades

Comment: Можно по сети (pxe, tftp) прогружаться, поднимать ssh и рулить удалённо. А если preseed файл подгружать - вообще всё само. Я к тому, что не обязательно резать болванку или кидать на флэшку.

Comment: @don_Rumata  Да, про PXE не упямянул. Так обычно локально пачками настраиваем. Задача стояла удаленно (в другой стране) обновить сервер, не теряя соединения, пройдя все 7 кругов ада с 9 по 16 :)

Comment: Ну могу сказать по опыту удалённого филиала за 300км от моего места работы. При наличии любого хоть как-то запускающегося компа на который можно воткнуть tftp, http и nfs (тот же debian жрал 30-40мб оперативы со всем установленным софтом) и ssh/vpn - лучше pxe с ssh на этапе прогрузки initrd\vmlinuz - самое рулезное решение.

Comment: Для меня осталось не понятным смогу ли я обновить ОС до новой версии используя старые репозитории или все-же стоит с 0 переустанавливать систему.

Answer (score 3):

Версии ubuntu с нечетными номерами 15, 17 и т.д. имеют небольшую поддержку по времени. Для 15 версии это время уже прошло. Вам стоит обновиться до какой-либо версии, которая имеет поддержку длительное время, такие версии называются lts(long term support). Версии Ubuntu lts поддерживаются в течении пяти лет. Т.е. обновления, например, для 16.04 lts вы будете получать вплоть до 2021 года.

Comment: Номера означают года. Время поддержки зависит, является ли версия LTS (чётный не значит LTS, к примеру 14.10 это не LTS это октябрь 2014). https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Comment: Точно. Забыл про десятые.

Comment: Это я знаю.
У меня вопрос собственно как обновить ос если репозитории не доступны.

Comment: @T1MOXA, репы недоступны потому что интерент отрубили или потому что пакетный менеджер в ошибку сваливается?

Comment: @donRumata 404 ошибка была.

Comment: @T1MOXA, значит те файлы индексов, которые бубен пытается качнуть - переместили.